# Create drupal (sub-)menu

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7

OK, so I have a weird thing to do, I'd appreciate any help. When you go to the Drupal admin panel and click `Structure`, you get a menu which contains `Blocks`, `Content types`, `Menus` and so on.

Is there a way I can programatically build one of those menus based on the path? For example if I have my module named `test` and all sub-actions of my module are located at `www.drupalsite.com/admin/test/action_name`, can I build my menu with all the `/test/action_name` there exist in the current module?

I know there's the option of hard-coding the menu, but I want to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be that descriptive without some more information but you'd just need to implement [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and loop through your list of actions, creating a menu item for each. Every time the menu is rebuilt your menu hook will be called and the current list of actions will be built as menu links. Something like this:

```
function mymodule_menu() {
  $actions = mymodule_get_actions_list();

  foreach ($actions as $action) {
    $items['admin/test/' . $action->name] = array(
      'title' => $action->name,
      'access arguments' => array('some permission'),
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_callback',
      'page_arguments' => array($action->name)
    );
  }


  return $items;
}

function mymodule_callback($action_name) {
  // Load the action and display the page
}
```

After you call your custom code to create one of these actions, be sure to call [`menu_rebuild()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_rebuild/7) so your hook runs and the new action is added to menu.

Comment: Thanks, but I know how to add the menu items, the thing I don't know is how to display them (and I'm not talking about displaying them in the top menu, cause I know they are added there automatically), but rather have them show up on a custom page.

Comment: Why not just call `mymodule_menu()` from your custom page and loop through the menu items?

Comment: Good idea, never thought of that. Will definitely try that.